# Increment groups of numbers in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, loops, for-loop, increment

In the scenario where you have two groups of numbers, each containing the numbers `1` to `10`, how would you go about incrementing each number until it hits its upper limit?

For example, to procude the numbers as follows:

```
1.1
1.2
1.3
```

`...`

```
1.9
1.10
2.1
2.2
2.3
```

`...`

```
2.9
2.10
```

etc...

My effort is pretty abysmal so far - I started with for loops and couldnt get a decent result, moved onto a while loop and still havent got a working solution, but here's what I have so far.

```
class Program
{
static void Main()
{
    int group01 = 1;
    int group01Max = 10;

    int group02 = 2;
    int group02Max = 10;

    while (group01 < group01Max)
    {
        while (group02 < group02Max)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}.{1}", group01, group02));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hello! What does your first attempt look like? Perhaps if you provide some code we can let you know what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're asking, but do you mean something like this?

```
a = 10
b = 10
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
    string tmp = i.toString();
    for(int j = 0; j < b; j++){
        tmp += "." + j.toString();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(tmp);
}
```

edit: using $"" notation would simplify this as done in the answer below

```
a = 10
b = 10
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){;
    for(int j = 0; j < b; j++){
        Console.WriteLine($"{i}.{j}");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much exactly what I was looking for, so minimal and clean, and works out the box!

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily done by nesting one loop in another loop.

```
foreach(var firstIndex in firstGroup)
{
    foreach(var secondIndex in secondGroup)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{firstIndex}.{secondIndex}");
    }
}
```

Comment: This works very much like the answer below, and gives the desired result, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(n1 => Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(n2 => (n1, n2)))
```

Or if you want the special formatting,

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10).SelectMany(n1 => Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(n2 => $"{n1}.{n2}"))
```

Comment: This wasnt something which crossed my mind, and I cant seem to get it to work. @Reese's answer does exactly what I'm looking for, but im curious of the output of this example, and the performance difference over a larger set of numbers

Comment: Try downloading LINQPad and running this?